# Grant Remote Access to mysql server installed on Google Compute Engine

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

i have followed all instructions give across google but somehow i am unable to get access from my desktop to a remote mysql database installed on Google Compute Engine.

I have done the following

a) create user and grant him permissions to get access remotely

[image]

b) allow the port in firewall
[image]

c) comment out `bind-address`
[image]

but still i get the error

[image]

when i try to connect from my remote windows client.

where i am i missing a required step??? Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have allowed TCP traffic from your location to VM in question to port 3306 on a project level in [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) or using CLI:

`gcloud compute firewall-rules list`

More about setting up firewalls in official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, google doesn't allow remote connections to a mysql DB on cloud engine. Only between VMs, but now with an external client.

It is only allowed if you are using a dedicated Cloud SQL instance

See the first paragraph on this article (I'd be happy to be proven wrong though):
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access

Answer (score 0):

Near the bottom they indicate non-compute engine access is out of scope for the article, but tells you to basically do the same stuff and set the google firewall for external access and the db user to access from outside.